# create and hide UILabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I created a `UILabel` programatically and triggering a button I would like to hide the same label. This is my code:

```
UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100)];
nameLabel.text = @"TEXT";
nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
nameLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
[self.view addSubview:nameLabel]; 

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hide" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(back)];    

- (IBAction)back{

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;

  [nameLabel setHidden: YES];  not working
   nameLabel.hidden = YES;     not working
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also another way to do same

```
UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100)];
nameLabel.text = @"TEXT";
nameLabel.tag = 1001;
nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
nameLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
[self.view addSubview:nameLabel]; 

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hide" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(back)];    

- (IBAction)back{

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
   UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1001];
  [tempLabel setHidden: YES];  
   tempLabel.hidden = YES;     
}
```

Comment: Thank you..I am quite new on programming. Could you explain me what is doing this line.  nameLabel.tag = 1001;    Thank you very much

Comment: This line give tag for this label. Tag is the identity of item in view. You can access items by their tag numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the button to be accessible from other methods, you need to assign it to an instance variable (whether directly or via a property) rather than assigning it to a local variable. The proper way to declare the property is

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *nameLabel;
```

which you can then assign to using

```
self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init...];
```

Later on, you can say

```
self.nameLabel.hidden = YES;
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know how that would even compile since the code you show to create `nameLabel` makes it local to whatever method that's in.  Try making `nameLabel` a property and using `self.nameLabel` whenever you reference it, either creating it or touching its properties.